# Null object reference on dialog button

Tags: android, button, dialog

im trying to pass a bundle with a dialog box which has 3 buttons but i get the error of null object reference here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reshte);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageButton zistbt=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
   zistbt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomDialogClass cdd=new CustomDialogClass(reshte.this);
        cdd.show();         
    }
});
}
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Button sat1,sat2,sat3;
public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
super(a);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.c = a;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.difselect);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new    ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
//buttons
sat1.setOnClickListener(this);
sat2.setOnClickListener(this);
sat3.setOnClickListener(this);

//font
final TextView textdialog = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txt_rate);
//font
String fontPath2 = "fonts/yekan.ttf";

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath2);
textdialog.setTypeface(tf2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    
    switch (v.getId()){ 
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(reshte.this,List1.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url","http://api.safshari.com/konkor/zist.json");
        bundle.putString("daste","zist");
        bundle.putString("sath","1");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
      break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(reshte.this,List1.class);
        Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putString("url","http://api.safshari.com/konkor/zist.json");
        bundle1.putString("daste","zist");
        bundle1.putString("sath","2");
        intent1.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(reshte.this,List1.class);
        Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
        bundle2.putString("url","http://api.safshari.com/konkor/zist.json");
        bundle2.putString("daste","zist");
        bundle2.putString("sath","3");
        intent2.putExtras(bundle2);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    }
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dismiss();
 }
 }
 }
```

and my log cat is without the on click listeners dialog is working great but when i i add them i get this error:

```
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822): Process: com.safshari.konkor, PID: 18822
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at com.safshari.konkor.reshte$CustomDialogClass.onCreate(reshte.java:52)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at com.safshari.konkor.reshte$1.onClick(reshte.java:31)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-04 12:50:34.947: E/AndroidRuntime(18822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: you have to initialize your buttons with findViewById

Comment: public Button sat1,sat2,sat3; where is the button initlization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your buttons before attaching the click listeners

```
sat1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sat1); //Replace sat1 with id defined in XML layout
```

Comment: what is `dismiss()` after all cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are not initialized yet, that's why they're passing null.

Initialize them First in your OnCreate